# Linux/Lubuntu, проблемы с памятью

Tags: linux, lubuntu, lxde

Подскажите, у меня в Lubuntu 18.04 - постоянно проблемы с памятью, при установке системы оставлял все по default (не настраивал разделы вручную). 
Память: 8GB

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  1,6M  783M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        37G   35G   78M 100% /
tmpfs           3,9G  145M  3,7G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      167M  167M     0 100% /snap/postman/121
/dev/loop1      145M  145M     0 100% /snap/code/41
/dev/loop2       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop3      145M  145M     0 100% /snap/code/40
/dev/loop4       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/sda1       487M  6,1M  481M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           785M   20K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop6      167M  167M     0 100% /snap/postman/122
```

Когда хочу установить какие-то `apt-пакеты`, то постоянно пишет, что нехватает памяти. 
Прописываю apt autoclean,  apt autoremove и т.п - помогает только навремя.

Подскажите, как правильно выделить место, чтобы при установке новых программ, не возникало с этим проблемы.
То, раньше использовал Ubuntu - с этим никогда не возникало проблем.

Comment: У вас 35 Гб какой-то шняги на диске, запускайте `du -s /*` и так далее до выяснения.

Comment: @0andriy Сорри, не особо в этом шарю. Вот, результат:  
 https://pastebin.com/fpxpCaiE  Там где "No such file or directory" удалять?

Comment: корневой раздел забит на 100%: `/dev/sda2        37G   35G   78M 100% /`. что тут ещё может не ясным?

Answer (score 3):

Запускаем `du -s /*` (или `du -sh /*` -- как читать удобней)

Что не знаем -- не удаляем. По крайней мере, пока не загуглим, и не убедимся, что можно.

Так, самые большие `/home` и `/var` -- по первому столбику.

Теперь смотрим внутри home: `du -s /home/*` и т. д.